# Sequentially naming variables (beginner)

Tags: r

I would like to assign data created within a loop to a corresponding series of sequentially- numbered variables.   As written, the loop in this example simply overwrites each time, so that all is stored is the final dataset assigned to matrix stooges.  What I would like to do is to have each iteration create a new variable, called “somename(counter)”, and store the current values for matrix stooges in that variable.  The loop below, then, should create variables somename0, with values 0,0,0,0, somename1, with values 1:4, and somename2 with values 2,4,6,8. I think creating the variables dynamically within the loop is best in order to automate the naming of the variables and how many are created.

ex:

```
no_its <- 3  
counter <- 0
while(counter < no_its){
    a <- c(counter*(1:4))
    stooges <- as.matrix(a)
    rownames(stooges)<-c("Larry","Moe","Curly","Shemp")
    counter <- counter+1
}
stooges

output:
      [,1]
Larry    2
Moe      4
Curly    6
Shemp    8
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use named variables instead of just creating a matrix or a dataframe or a list or any of the data structures that are much more suited for this task?

Comment: The R way to do this is to make your loop store each iteration as a new element in a list.  Then it's easy to iterate over the list systematically.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f

Answer (score 2):

Try using lists, it will always prove a better choice in R

```
counter <- 0:2
names(counter) <- paste("somename",seq_along(counter)-1,sep="")
(result <- lapply(counter, function(counter) counter*1:4))
result[["somename1"]]
## only if you must
attach(result, pos=2)
ls(pos=2)
```

Comment: Ok, I may have failed to articulate my situation well.  My actual code is much more complex than the simple example described above.  My input data is a matrix with rownames listing taxa and column names listing samples.  Iterations of the loop create random (or probability-weighted) subsamples of the input martix and, thus, generate matrices with a constant number of columns, but a variable (and unknown) number of rows.  I need to assign a name to each output matrix, so that I can refer them for use later.

Comment: the same idea should apply no matter how complex the function called by `lapply`; that's the beauty of it.

Comment: Thanks very much.  With a bit of tweaking, your code does the job.  Apologies for the amateurish question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a matrix, then create an empty matrix and then populate it:

```
 stooges <- matrix(NA, ncol=4, nrow=4)
 row.names(stooges)<-c("Larry","Moe","Curly","Shemp")
 stooges[1:4, 1:4] <- col(stooges) * 1:4
 stooges
#---------
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
Larry    1    2    3    4
Moe      2    4    6    8
Curly    3    6    9   12
Shemp    4    8   12   16
```